# Jquery Autocomplete Response

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomplete in my form. After selecting the value from autocomplete, I want to fetch that value and pass in another jquery function. And based on that selected value I need to put another autosuggest on the same textbox.

```
$("#pickUpID").autocomplete("auto_suggest.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    //mustMatch: true,
    //minChars: 0,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: false,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    selectFirst: false
});
```

After this I want to fetch the value of pickUpID and send to another jquery function.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: (not tested)

```
$("#pickUpID").autocomplete("auto_suggest.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    //mustMatch: true,
    //minChars: 0,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: false,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    selectFirst: false
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    // your function call
    myFunction(data);

   // update with another result
   $(this).val('another computed value');
})
```

As in documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler